# MariaDB opens lots of files causing PHP-FPM to fail

Tags: nginx, mysql, php-fpm, mariadb

There is a problem I'm dealing with that under a known traffic (e.g. reaching 300 concurrent users) server doesn't handle more incoming requests due to `open files`. This is the current limit:

```
$ cat /etc/security/limits.conf
* - nofile 1000000
```

Error comes into sight from within `php-fpm` error.log file:

```
[16-Aug-2019 02:14:12] WARNING: [pool ****] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 99 idle, and 506 total children
[16-Aug-2019 02:14:12] ERROR: failed to prepare the stderr pipe: Too many open files (24)
```

At this moment `nginx` responds with `499` status code.

I can see that when no requests are made `mysqld` has this number of open files (default number?):

```
$ lsof | grep '^mysqld' | wc -l
104104
```

While under load it goes up to a number like `603035` and then those errors from `php-fpm` trigger.

Server doesn't reach 10% CPU load and most of RAM is free. How can I avoid such number of open files or if not possible what should be done and investigated in this situation?

More information:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 385941
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1000000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: What are the values of `table_open_cache` and `max_connections`?  How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Why are you checking the number of open files of MariaDB, when PHP is the program which cannot open files?

Comment: @RickJames the former has `1485` and the latter `5000` value. Server has `94` GB RAM.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well I thought this number of open files of `mysqld` could be related since `php-fpm` starts with `500` processes and ~58000 open files (seeing as `root`) and it doesn't grow until available processes go busy and when it does the error happens. But recently I found that I can't increase `pm.start_servers` from `500` to for example `700` because of the same error: `Too many open files`. Which may mean looking at `mysqld` open files is not be very related?

Comment: Correct, `php-fpm` is having the problem with too many open files, not `mysqld`. So there is no use to look at the MariaDB configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton But does not it mean that if open file limits is `1000000` and MariaDB consumed 600K of this number, php-fpm only has 400K at maximum (which actually never happens because of other processes too)?

Comment: @rev Please provide TEXT OS command prompt results of ulimit -a (Open Files limit is critical) when dealing with this volume of open tables.  It sounds like your software is NOT releasing resources (tables) when no longer needed by the processing.  Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile with downloadable FREE utility scripts and contact information.

Comment: What does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` in the MariaDB console show?

Comment: @WilsonHauck Added to the question.

Comment: @Machavity Do you mean when php-fpm gives error?

Comment: @rev Yes. Around that time, what is MariaDB doing?